# Why timeout called by python subprocess hangs its called shell program?

Tags: python, timeout

My program is like

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(f"timeout -s 9 30 cat", shell=True)
```

However, it has no reaction to input from tty.

Removing timeout or running the full command in a normal tty shell acts as expected.

What causes the hanging in python?

Environment:

```
$ uname -rv
5.10.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.106-1 (2022-03-17)
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ dpkg -l | grep dash
ii  dash                              0.5.11+git20200708+dd9ef66-5   amd64        POSIX-compliant shell
```

Comment: But why using cat without timeout works?

Comment: Hm ok my assumption was wrong, please excuse

Comment: Using `subprocess.run(f"cat", shell=True)` acts like running cat in bash, which prints what I typed before every \n